# What if an automorphism fixes every maximal subgroup pointwise. Is it then the identity?

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group, maximal-subgroup, frattini-subgroup

This question came up in the discussion over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4338646/1007655)

My first thought was that then it fixes the Frattini subgroup.   Any help?

For reference we found that the answer is no when each maximal subgroup is merely mapped back to itself.

Comment: With questions like this, one of the first things you should do is to look for small counterexamples. Did you do that?  You don't have to look far. The cyclic group of order $3$ is a counterexample. You might try and prove that, for finite groups, the only counterexamples are cyclic groups of prime power order.

Comment: To be honest I used most of my RAM posing the question.   What you propose looks feasible.   I'll think about it.  @Derek Holt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small counterexample: $G=C_4$, the cyclic group of order 4, say generated by $a$. The automorphism $a \rightarrow  a^{-1}$, fixes  the maximal subgroup $ \langle a^2 \rangle$ pointwise.

Comment: Yeah,  here the Frattini is large as can be.

Comment: $G = C_3$ also works.

Comment: @Derek Holt vacuously for any $C_p,\,p\gt2$.  Or, the Frattini is  $0$, I should say.

Comment: Yes, on purpose I did not take that example to avoid an example like Alon Amit's below (which one is perfectly OK of course).

Comment: @Cpc To be more precise, in $C_p$,  the trivial subgroup, which contains just the identity element, is a maximal subgroup, and is also equal to the Frattini subgroup. In $({\mathbb Q},+)$ on the other hand, there are no maximal subgroups, and so the Frattini subgroup is the intersection of an empty set of subgroups, which is (by definition) equal to the whole group.

Answer (score 7):

The additive group of the rational numbers has no maximal subgroups, yet it admits many non-trivial automorphisms $x \mapsto kx$ for fixed $k \ne 0$.

Comment: Very sneaky....

Comment: @Cpc Not at all. This should always be your first thought: your condition says that all borogoves are mimsy… what if there aren’t any? Or just one? Take things to extreme.

Comment: Right.  Maybe I could also add the condition that $G$ isn't its Frattini subgroup.

Comment: @Cpc I wouldn’t expect this to change things. The Frattini can still be large, and still admit non-trivial automorphisms which fix the rest of the group.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this answers the question. The automorphisms here don't fix maximal subgroups pointwise (as there are no maximal subgroups to fix).

Comment: Since there are no maximal subgroups, of course these automorphisms fix their elements pointwise (“vacuously”).