# Finitely generated group has automorphism mapping between two elements of the same order?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, finitely-generated

For a finitely generated group $G$, is it always the case that if two elements $g_1, g_2$ have the same order then there is an automorphism that sends one to the other (i.e. $\phi$ such that $\phi(g_1)=g_2$)?

I can't seem to prove it, but playing around with several groups, abelian or not (to include $D_3$; a cyclic group of prime order and $\mathbb{Z}_4$), I'm unable to refute this.

How could one go about proving this? (assuming indeed it can be proven).

Comment: My first thought is to look at semidirect products as a potential source of counterexamples; however, I'm not sure how to justify that idea.

Comment: @Shaun I actually thought of that (!) so I'm glad you're saying this. I wasn't able to think of how to find a counter example though.

Comment: Take any finite group with two conjugacy classes of elements of the same order, but the classes have different sizes.

Comment: The smallest counterexample is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$. There are three elements of order $2$ there, but when you take $g$ of order four, then $g+g$ has just one possible value.

Comment: One of the simplest examples is the infinite cyclic group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $G=S_3\times\mathbb{Z_2}$. It contains an element of order $2$ which is in the center, and an element of order $2$ not in the center. So clearly there is no automorphism which maps one of these elements to the other one.

Answer (score 3):

In $S_4$ there is no automorphism that takes a two cycle like $(12)$ to a product of two cycles like $(12)(34)$.

In general, $S_n$ has only inner automorphisms when $n \ne 2,6$ and those preserve cycle structure, so you can construct lots of similar examples.

Comment: Can I ask - how did you think of this? Was it just trial and error or something that popped into mind or is there some guiding principle you used?

Comment: From the start I was pretty sure the conjecture was false, so I looked for a counterexample. The smallest decently compicated group is $S_4$. There are two different kinds of permutations of order $2$ there. If there's a guiding principle it's that it's useful to be familiar with lots of examples, particularly the symmetric groups.

Answer (score 1):

Automorphisms send conjugacy classes to conjugacy classes, while preserving elements' order. In $S_4$, the only distinct conjugacy classes of elements of the same order are the class of the transpositions and the class of the double transpositions. But the former has size $6$, whereas the latter has size $3$, so no one automorphism of $S_4$ sends transpositions to double transpositions, despite having the elements of both classes order $2$. Yet another affordable case where this argument works, *verbatim*, is $S_5$.  (Incidentally, this proves also that in these two groups the automorphisms are class-preserving, and hence inner.)

Comment: Not all automorphisms are class preserving.   See this old post of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4075551/1070376. Inner automorphisms do though.   So when $n\neq2,6,$ you are good in $S_n.$  Also I missed the argument that the automorphisms in $S_4,S_5$ are all inner.

Comment: You even acknowledged this in your answer there.