# What does the Outer automorphism group act on? If an automorphism preserves conjugacy classes, is it inner?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, automorphism-group

(Let $x^G:=\{gxg^{-1}:g\in G\}$ denote the conjugacy class of $x$)

Am I right in thinking $\text{Out }G := \text{Aut }G/\text{Inn }G$ acts on the conjugacy classes of G, $\{x^G:x\in G\}$? What else could I think of it acting on (trying to get some intuition)?

In addition to that, if $f\in \text{Aut }G$

$$f\in\text{Inn }G\iff(\forall x\in G)f(x^G) = x^G$$

I feel this must be true, but couldn't find anything on it.

If it is true, can we find a weaker condition on the right hand side to check if $f\in\text{Inn }G$? eg. we only require $f(x^G) = x^G$ for $x$ in a set of generators for this to be true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\mathrm{Out}G$ acts on the set of conjugacy classes.

Your claim is not true for some infinite groups. An automorphism preserving conjugacy classes is called a *conjugating automorphism* or *class preserving automorphism* and the property that every conjugating automorphism is inner is called the Grossman property. See, for example [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504212.pdf) or [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185866/outer-automorphisms-of-direct-product-of-residually-finite-groups) .

For finite groups there is apparently a theorem by Gary Seitz and Walter Feit (1984) that finite simple groups satisfy the Grossman property (I could not find the paper). But in general for finite groups it is [not true](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-12/S0002-9939-03-06974-0/S0002-9939-03-06974-0.pdf),

Comment: Seemingly, Burnside himself found out a finte group violating Grossman's property: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838188/inner-automorphism-group-as-the-kernel-of-a-homomorphism#comment7918217_3838521

Comment: Could be. ${}{}$ See https://owd.tcnj.edu/~mizuharm/research/burnside-involve-FINAL.pdf

Comment: Indeed, therein ref. "$\textbf[Bu2]$" is probably the one I referred to.

Comment: The interesting question is to find the paper by Gary Seitz and Walter Feit. Mathsci lists one paper by these authors: Feit, Walter (1-YALE); Seitz, Gary M. (1-OR)
On finite rational groups and related topics.
Illinois J. Math. 33 (1989), no. 1, 103–131. 
But is was published in 1989

Comment: ... that paper does contain the result.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example where the Grossman property is violated:

Let $X$ be an infinite set. A permutation $\alpha$ of $X$ is said to have **finite support**  if there exists a finite subset $F\subset X$ such that $\alpha$ fixes every element of $X-F$.

The set $Aut_f(X)$ of permutations of $X$ with finite support clearly form a normal subgroup of the group $Aut(X)$ of all permutations of $X$.

Suppose that $\alpha$ is any permutation of $X$. Then for every permutation $\beta\in Aut_f(X)$, the permutations $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}$ and $\beta$ are conjugate not only in $Aut(X)$, but also in $Aut_f(X)$ (I leave it to you as an exercise to prove this). At the same time, for each $\alpha$ with infinite support, the automorphism of $Aut_f(X)$ defined by
$$
\beta \mapsto \alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}
$$
is not inner (as an automorphism of $Aut_f(X)$). This is another easy exercise.

Comment: Thank you for the simple example :)

Comment: I think the roles of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should be switched; i.e. $\alpha$ should be finitely supported and $\beta$ should be arbitrary.

Comment: Also, I think it is better to write $Sym(X)$ and $Sym_f(X)$ (symmetric group, not necessarily automorphism group since X is just a set). Letting $X = \mathbb Z, \beta(n) = n+1$, I can see this example works, though.

Comment: @RaviFernando: Right, I mixed up the names of the permutations. Corrected now.